# Sqlite3 find changes in row values

Tags: python-3.x, database, pandas, sqlite, triggers

I am collecting marine AIS data that looks like the following into a sqlite3 database using Python;

```
|MMSI|TSTAMP|LATITUDE|LONGITUDE|COG|SOG|HEADING|NAVSTAT|IMO|NAME|CALLSIGN|TYPE|A|B|C|D|DRAUGHT|DEST|ETA|MGRS|UNIQUEREF|
636018508|1576547278|36.48892|14.52537|286.0|6.2|284|5|9481960|BRIGHT STAR|D5QA2|79.0|149.0|31.0|9.0|21.0|9.8|DZGHZ|12-19 11:00|33SVA57483828|636018508-1576547278.0
636018508|1576547158|36.48695|14.5334|286.0|12.1|284|0|9481960|BRIGHT STAR|D5QA2|79.0|149.0|31.0|9.0|21.0|9.8|DZGHZ|12-19 11:00|33SVA58203806|636018508-1576547158.0
636018508|1576547098|36.486|14.53742|286.0|12.1|284|0|9481960|BRIGHT STAR|D5QA2|79.0|149.0|31.0|9.0|21.0|9.8|DZGHZ|12-19 11:00|33SVA58563795|636018508-1576547098.0
636018508|1576546858|36.48185|14.55417|284.0|12.2|284|0|9481960|BRIGHT STAR|D5QA2|79.0|149.0|31.0|9.0|21.0|9.8|DZGHZ|12-19 11:00|33SVA60063748|636018508-1576546858.0
636018508|1576545900|36.46573|14.6182|289.0|12.2|288|0|9481960|BRIGHT STAR|D5QA2|79.0|149.0|31.0|9.0|21.0|9.8|DZGHZ|12-19 11:00|33SVA65793567|636018508-1576545900.0
```

The data is downloaded every minute by python inserted into a temp table by pandas. To avoid duplicate rows the last field is a combination of the first two fields(DateTime epoch & unique ID) concatenated together which gives each row a unique ID. Then in my main table, I have then set a column with a unique constraint.

The data is then copied across using;

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO <main table> FROM <temp table>;
```

I want to keep all the data in the main table so as to build a historical database however I also need to monitor for changes in certain fields. For example, in the data snippet, you can see that in the top row the 7th field has changed from 12.1 to 6.2  and the 8th field has changed from 0 to 5. The top row is the most recent update as it has the newest Epoch. The problem is that the main database is going to be very big(49487034 rows at present) and I need to detect any changes on all new rows downloaded in < 1 minute before the most recent data comes in.

What I have tried so far;

```
GROUP BY unique MMSI ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Then using conditional statements to check for changes. The problem is that by doing this its taking way to long since we are filtering the whole db then sorting all records then checking for changes.

I am not the most experienced programmer but I would say that I need to use a more vectorized approach opposed to what is, in essence, a loop.

A second thought I had was to build a third table that also takes data from the temp table however it then only holds the most recent 2 updates however from a database POV I am not sure as to how this will affect the database as a whole and also not sure if there is a quicker way of achieving what I want.

My last idea was to use a trigger however surely this would only be as fast as my second idea above?

Looking for any advice on how I can identify these changes in sub < 1 minute? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing that concatenation thing instead of just making the first two columns the PK or unique (really the same thing in sqlite unless it's a without rowid table)?

Comment: I wasn't aware I could make a PK or unique constraint using 2 columns and that's why I decided to create a unique reference. Do you have any links to demonstrate what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html etc.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_primary_key.htm thanks for this I will modify my code to use this instead of the uniqueRef (less storage!). Its called a composite key.

Comment: Like many tutorialspoint articles I've looked at, that one is outright wrong. Sqlite doesn't support that form of `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lag()` window function (Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer) to compare values of the current row to those of the previous row and only select those that are different. Something like:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT mmsi, tstamp, sog, navstat
       , lag(sog, 1) OVER previous AS prev_sog
       , lag(navstat, 1) OVER previous AS prev_navstat
  FROM data
  WINDOW previous AS (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY tstamp))
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE sog <> prev_sog OR navstat <> prev_navstat
ORDER BY mmsi, tstamp;
```

[db-fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pkTBkgf3WKmwj76m6V47EQ/0)

If you want to limit it to just rows with a timestamp dating from the last minute, you can add a where clause using `strftime()`:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT mmsi, tstamp, sog, navstat
       , lag(sog, 1) OVER previous AS prev_sog
       , lag(navstat, 1) OVER previous AS prev_navstat
  FROM data
  WHERE tstamp >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 minute')
  WINDOW previous AS (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY tstamp))
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE sog <> prev_sog OR navstat <> prev_navstat
ORDER BY mmsi, tstamp;
```

Comment: How could I insert the results from this into a different table?